# Does a code transformer / formatter exist that will add curly braces to Typescript code

Tags: javascript, typescript, code-formatting

I want all the code in our repository to always use blocks enclosed with brackets for the clauses of if statements, loops and even for inline functions. The following code is banned:

```
const func = () => doSomething();
```

It should be converted to:

```
const func = () => {
  return doSomething();
};
```

It's personal preference, of course, but I think if only the latter is checked in, then diffs are easier to read, it's easier to add and remove debug logging, and you are less likely to accidentally check in changes that have no impact on the logic.

Prettier won't do this, it is considered beyond its scope. But there must be some tools that do it. I've done google searches but found nothing.

Comment: Have you thought about using Regular Expressions?

Comment: I believe the quick fix that IDEs offer for this specific case is provided directly by the typescript language service.

Comment: You could just have a build step that rejects this code, rather than something that fixes it. Team members would soon learn that they need the braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESLint has the [arrow-body-style always](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/arrow-body-style) option, which supports autofixing.